# call one fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I am new in android developing.
I have one Activity and two fragments.in the second fragment(EditProfileFragment) I have a button for contact information update called UPDATE.
I want after clicking update button, first fragment(ProfileFragment)be replaced with second fragment(EditProfileFragment).
in activity I use two fragment like this:

```
private void initFragment() {
    fragments = new Vector<>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ProfileFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, EditProfileFragment.class.getName()));
    adapterFragment = new PagerAdapterFragment(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpg_main_content);
    pager.setAdapter(adapterFragment);

}


private ProfileFragment getProfileFragment() {
    if (profileFragment == null) {
        profileFragment = (ProfileFragment) fragments.get(0);
    }
    return profileFragment;
}

private EditProfileFragment getEditProfileFragment() {
    if (editProfileFragment == null) {
        editProfileFragment = (EditProfileFragment) fragments.get(1);
    }
    return editProfileFragment;
}
```

and my Fragment adapter is :

```
public class PagerAdapterFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> fragments;
public PagerAdapterFragment(FragmentManager fm, 
List<Fragment> fragments)   {
super(fm);
this.fragments = fragments;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
return this.fragments.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

this is my Update statement:

```
       fragmentEditBtUpdate.setOnClickListener(
       new View.OnClickListener()   {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       id = contact.get_id();
       name = fragmentEditEditTextName.getText().toString();
       family = fragmentEditEditTextFamily.getText().toString();
       phoneNumber = fragmentEditEditTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
       contact = new Contact(id, name, family, phoneNumber,
       mCurrentImagePath);
       rowUpdate =
       App.getInstanceImplementation().updateContact(contact);
            Log.i("==>", "btnUpdateContact: " + rowUpdate);
       editFragmentCallBack.setCurrentFragmentPosition();

        }
    });
```

I create callBack listener in EditProfileFragment:

```
    public interface EditFragmentCallBack 
    {
    Contact getContact();
    void finishProfile();
    void setCurrentFragmentPosition();
    }
```

and implemented in activity:

```
    @Override
public void setCurrentFragmentPosition() {
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.vpg_main_content,profileFragment);
}
```

this is Activity Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.sayres.myapplication7.mvp.view.profile.ProfileActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpg_main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

but when I am clicking on button and call `editFragmentCallBack.setCurrentFragmentPosition();`, nothing Happens!
what is your opinion?

Comment: do you want to move to fragment from activity ?

Comment: @sasikumar No I want to go to another fragment by Activity

Comment: @sayreskabir did you solve the problem??

Comment: @CoDFather Hi buddy , Yes .By using setCurrentItem() from ViewPager,finally I could fixed my problem.after clicking on my Update button I run   setCurrentItem in this way :`vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some change in structure of my program and Use of View Pager setCurrentItem() method, I finally could fix my problem.this link was very helpful for me.  [guides.codepath.com](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter#setup-fragmentpageradapter)

Answer (score 0):

If you initialized a transaction with `beginTransaction()` you should commit it by `commit()`

So use this

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.vpg_main_content,profileFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Put it in `setCurrentFragmentPosition()` and replace

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.vpg_main_content,profileFragment);
```

## Edit

```
private void initFragment() {
    List<Fragments> fragments=new ArrayList<> //declare it as global
    fragments.add(new ProfileFragment.class);
    fragments.add(new EditProfileFragment.class);
    adapterFragment = new PagerAdapterFragment(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpg_main_content);
    pager.setAdapter(adapterFragment);

}


private ProfileFragment getProfileFragment() {
    if (profileFragment == null) {
        profileFragment = (ProfileFragment) fragments.get(0);
    }
    return profileFragment;
}

private EditProfileFragment getEditProfileFragment() {
    if (editProfileFragment == null) {
        editProfileFragment = (EditProfileFragment) fragments.get(1);
    }
    return editProfileFragment;
}
```

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: @sayreskabir then shows that error log of nullpointer exception completly

Comment: Actually it stays at fragment but all view is gone ,that mean the feragment be white. then I got Error

Comment: @sayreskabir remove `.getName()` also from adding to list

Comment: declare List as global @sayreskabir

Comment: List<Fragments> ? is it true?I could not add `Fragments.add(ProfileFragment.class);` to de list!!![link](http://codepad.org/Gao6jEdB)

Comment: @sayreskabir sorry my mistake use new keyword and add like `fragments.add(new ProfileFragment.class);`

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity class that you want to go for fragment

**Activity Class**

```
 FragmentClass fragClass = FragmentClass.newInstance(You can send any data to fragment class);
 fragClass.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "");
```

**Fragment Class**

```
 public static FragmentClass newInstance(Get Any Data from Activity Class) {
    FragmentClass fragClass = new FragmentClass();

    return fragClass;
   }
```

Comment: look buddy, I am in fragment. I want after clicking on button in fragment, go to another fragment. my code is above.